# Electron File Download using fs.createWriteStream makes corrupted files

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, fs, electron

I'm trying to download files in an Electron app using Dialog and fs, but I'm getting files that are corrupted.

```
dialog.showSaveDialog({ title: 'Downloader', defaultPath: '/' + fileName },
                function (filePath) {
                    var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {defaultEncoding: 'binary'});
                    fileStream.on('open', function(fd) {
                        $http.get(url + fileName)
                            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                                fileStream.write(data);
                                fileStream.end();
                            })
                            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                                console.log('product download failed');
                            });
                    });
                });
```

I attempted downloading a basic .txt file with using this code and the file came through fine and opened uncorrupted. But anything larger gives me a corrupted file(.rar & .zip files).

Comment: I posted this on the Electron forum and received the following response from 'leedohm'.

"The file is corrupt because the default encoding for fs.createWriteStream1 is UTF-8 ... within which some byte values or byte patterns are invalid
You don't see this problem when downloading a text file because it is stored in UTF-8 (or it is "7-bit clean" so it doesn't matter what encoding you're using)
Solution if the above is correct: change the defaultEncoding to binary."
This fixed the file size issue. But the files are still corrupted. Will update this post when I find a solution to that issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue?